# Occasional <Paste> when pasting with Vim

Tags: vim

Occasionally, when pasting with Vim, I get the text `<Paste>` showing up after the content I've yanked. It seems random. I'm not sure what is causing it. There doesn't seem to be a pattern.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE**
I'm using Neovim (v0.1.5-561-gbd6dad0) within tmux (2.2).

I'm yanking with `y` and pasting with `p`.

Comment: Console Vim, or gVim? What method are you using to paste? (Keyboard shortcut, mouse, Vim's clipboard register, etc.)

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: Unless you have mappings for `y` and/or `p`, this sound like a bug in NeoVim.